# Unable to post a http request with json body because jsonEncode method from 'dart:convert' package adding escape character

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart

I am trying to make an http post request using http/http.dart package with a JSON body. For that I am trying to convert a Map to JSON using jsonEncode (dart:convert package) but unable to do so as jsonEncode is adding escape character during conversion which makes the JSON string an invalid JSON for post.

```
Future postData(Map data) async {
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};

var body = jsonEncode(data);

http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  print("Customer creared");
  } else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  }
}
```

When I am debugging above code the value for body is coming as below:

```
body = {\"first_name\":\"Manish\",\"last_name\":\"Kumar\",\"phone_numebr\":\"9123456789\",\"seal\":\"manne\"}
```

So here I can see an extra escape character being added to the json string which is making it hard to make an http post request with json body.

I tried making http post request by directly placing this string and it worked fine. Code below:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: '{"first_name":"Manish","last_name":"Kumar","phone_numebr":"9123456789","seal":"manne"}');
```

Can someone please help me converting a Map to json without escape characters?

Comment: In my case, I just put the body with Map type into it and it work fine

Comment: @hoangquyy - When I am putting body with Map and without header. The url is giving bad request and when I am putting body with Map and with json header, it says `Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"`

Comment: Try this 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Still getting bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.

I created a dataTest variable as below:

```
final dataTest = {
  'first_name': firstName,
  'last_name': lastName,
  'seal': seal,
  'phone_number': phoneNumber
};
```

Here firstName, lastName, seal and phoneNumber are of string type.

Now call,

```
postData(dataTest);

Future postData(dynamic data) async {
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};

http.Response response = await http
    .post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(data));

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
 print("Customer creared");
 } else {
 print(response.statusCode);
 }
}
```

So here the key is to call json.encode method on dynamic type and then pass it to the body parameter of http.post.